# Changing the limits when integrating

Tags: calculus

When doing integration by substitution and changing the limits, how do you know which limit to change it to if there are two possibilities?  For example, if the substitution is 
$u = \cos^{-1}(x)$ and the original limits were $x=0$ to $x=1$, should you change the limit $x=0$ to $u = \pi/2$ or $u = 3 \pi/2$?

Comment: In this case, you choose $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because the cosine-function is invertible in the interval [$0,\frac{\pi}{2}$], but not in the interval [$0,\frac{3\pi}{2}$].

Comment: Just following up on Peter's comment, suppose that $\cos^{-1}(0)$ has 2 possible values, then $\cos^-1$ wouldn't be a function by the "vertical-line test" (see discussion at http://mathuprising.comlu.com/inverse-functions.html). It would be a relation.